# GraphQL circular queries with one to many relationships

Tags: graphql, graphene-python

I'm learning GraphQL by building a simple python application, basically runs `nmap` scans stores output to a database, and can be queried by a GraphQL API. I seem to be a bit confused on how GraphQL works.

I have a few tables that are one-to-many relationships: `user has many scans`, `scans have results`, `results have hosts`, `hosts have ports`, `hosts have os`. Which I defined using `sqlalchemy` and used `graphene`

Now, in my GraphQL schema I have:

```
class Scans(SQLAlchemyObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = ScansModel


class ScanResult(SQLAlchemyObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = ScanResultModel


class Hosts(SQLAlchemyObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = HostInfoModel


class Ports(SQLAlchemyObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = PortInfoModel


class Os(SQLAlchemyObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = OsInfoModel

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    user = graphene.Field(User)
    scans = graphene.List(Scans)
    scan_results = graphene.List(ScanResult)
    hosts = graphene.List(Hosts)
    ports = graphene.List(Ports)
    os = graphene.Field(Os)

    def resolve_scans(self, info):
        query = Scans.get_query(info)
        return query
```

Now, when I make a GraphQL query, I can query scans, results, hostinfo, portinfo, osinfo, without having to have resolvers for those fields.  I was under the impression that each of those fields would need a resolver.

Furthermore, I seem to be able to do circular queries (so from `scanresults` I can query `scans` and from `scans` I can query `user`) due to the foreign keys and relationship table.

Is this the correct behaviour, or am misunderstanding how GraphQL works?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is:

```py
class ScanResult(SQLAlchemyObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = ScanResultModel

    scans = graphene.List(Scans, description="Scans from results.")

    def resolve_scans(self, info):
        query = Scans.get_query(info)
        return query.filter(ScansModel.my_id == self.scans_id).all()
```

This will probably enables you to build queries like:

```
{
  scanresult{
    edges {
      node {
         id
         scans{
            id
         }
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I know that resolvers for each field with SQLAlchemyObjecType are handled inside the library.

when I use mongoengine without using MongoengineObjectType, I code like this.

```
class Query(graphene.ObjectType):

    department = graphene.List(of_type=DepartmentField,
                           name=graphene.String(default_value="all"))

    role = graphene.List(of_type=RoleField,
                     name=graphene.String(default_value="all"))

    employee = graphene.List(of_type=EmployeeField,
                         name=graphene.String(default_value="all"))

    def resolve_department(self, info, name):
        if name == "all":
            department = [construct(DepartmentField, object) for object in DepartmentModel.objects]
            return department
        else:
            department = DepartmentModel.objects.get(name=name)
            return [construct(DepartmentField, department)]

    def resolve_role(self, info, name):
            .
            .
            .
```